# How do I make this layout (with css-grid)?

Tags: css, css-grid

[The layout I need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNRQq.png)

I'm doing a website for a beginner class in web development and we can only use html and css for this. So I think I have to use grid, right? The biggest problem is putting the yellow section to the right of the text, though I can easily make the yellow grid itself. What I don't understand is if the text is supposed to be in the same grid as the yellow or outside of it. Also I assume the orange part should be its own grid. I've already tried all the options I can think of but none of them work. So, how do I do to position these three parts (text, yellow and orange) on the page? The following html was provided by the teacher, we can't change it except for adding classes.

```
 <article id="spring" class="best">

                    <div class="album_data">
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="h1-spring">SZNZ: Spring</h1>
                            <h2 class="h2-spring">Released March 2022</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="musicians">
                            <p>Musicians:</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Rivers Cuomo, Lead vocals, backing vocals, lead guitar, rhythm guitar & writer</li>
                                <li>Patrick Wilson, Drums & Writer</li>
                                <li>Brian Bell, Backing vocals & lead guitar</li>
                                <li>Scott Shriner, Backing vocals & bass</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="album_description">
                            <p>SZNZ is a musical project by Weezer planned for
                                release throughout 2022. The project is a collection of four short studio records to be
                                released on the first day of each seasonal solstice, with each having its own motif,
                                aesthetic themes, and production style based on the corresponding season. SZNZ: Spring
                                is the first (of four) in the SZNZ series of EPs by Weezer.
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="cover">
                        <img class="show_hover" src="Weezer-2.jpg">
                        <img class="show_not_hover" src="Spring.jpg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="song_list">
                        <div>
                            <h2>Tracks</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Opening Night</li>
                                <li>Angels on Vacation</li>
                                <li>A Little Bit of Love</li>
                                <li>The Garden of Eden</li>
                                <li>The Sound of Drums</li>
                                <li>All This Love</li>
                                <li>Wild at heart</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Side Two</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li>The Wind Cries Mary</li>
                                <li>Fire</li>
                                <li>3rd Stone from the Sun</li>
                                <li>Foxey Lady</li>
                                <li>Are You Experienced?</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="anecdotes">
                        <li class="top_right_90">The album was produced by Weezer's frequent collaborators Jake Sinclair
                            and Suzy Shinn, as well as new collaborator Ethan Gruska.</li>
                        <li class="empty"></li>
                        <li class="two_wide bottom_left_90">The budget for the recordings was rather limited so Chas
                            Chandler (producer) and Hendrix completed much of the album's pre-production work at their
                            shared apartment.</li>
                        <li class="empty tablet_empty"></li>
                        <li class="empty phone_empty"></li>
                        <li class="image image_1 top_left_90">Chas Chandler, producer</li>
                        <li class="bottom_right_90">Are You Experienced sold more than one million copies within seven
                            months of its release.</li>
                    </ul>

                </article>
```

Here's the css I've tried, this is my first time posting so I don't know what you need to see. I've made a grid but realize that it's probably not right.

```
article {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(227, 227, 227, 0.4);
    padding: 20px;
}

.album_data {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 550px 300px;
}


.h1-spring {
    font-family: Piximisa;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 5vw;
    color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.7);
    margin: 0;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.h2-spring {
    font-family: Louis;
    font-size: 2.4vw;
    color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.musicians {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


li {
    list-style: none;
}

.show_not_hover {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}
```

I'm very confused with my grid so I'd rather just start over with it. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one possible solution:

```css
.best {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.best>* {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.album_data {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.cover, .song_list {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.show_hover, .cover:hover .show_not_hover {
  display: none;
}

.cover:hover .show_hover {
  display: initial;
}

.song_list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

.song_list>* {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}

.anecdotes {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.anecdotes li {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<article id="spring" class="best">

  <div class="album_data">
    <div>
      <h1 class="h1-spring">SZNZ: Spring</h1>
      <h2 class="h2-spring">Released March 2022</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="musicians">
      <p>Musicians:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Rivers Cuomo, Lead vocals, backing vocals, lead guitar, rhythm guitar & writer</li>
        <li>Patrick Wilson, Drums & Writer</li>
        <li>Brian Bell, Backing vocals & lead guitar</li>
        <li>Scott Shriner, Backing vocals & bass</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="album_description">
      <p>SZNZ is a musical project by Weezer planned for release throughout 2022. The project is a collection of four short studio records to be released on the first day of each seasonal solstice, with each having its own motif, aesthetic themes, and production style based on the corresponding season. SZNZ: Spring is the first (of four) in the SZNZ series of EPs by Weezer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cover">
    <img class="show_hover" src="https://images.genius.com/346247eb9a479e6d2818762a9ceaf27f.996x996x1.jpg">
    <img class="show_not_hover" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Michael_Jackson_-_Bad.png">
  </div>

  <div class="song_list">
    <div>
      <h2>Tracks</h2>
      <ul>
                                <li>Opening Night</li>
                                <li>Angels on Vacation</li>
                                <li>A Little Bit of Love</li>
                                <li>The Garden of Eden</li>
                                <li>The Sound of Drums</li>
                                <li>All This Love</li>
                                <li>Wild at heart</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Side Two</h2>
      <ul>
                                <li>The Wind Cries Mary</li>
                                <li>Fire</li>
                                <li>3rd Stone from the Sun</li>
                                <li>Foxey Lady</li>
                                <li>Are You Experienced?</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="anecdotes">
                        <li class="top_right_90">The album was produced by Weezer's frequent collaborators Jake Sinclair
                            and Suzy Shinn, as well as new collaborator Ethan Gruska.</li>
                        <li class="empty"></li>
                        <li class="two_wide bottom_left_90">The budget for the recordings was rather limited so Chas
                            Chandler (producer) and Hendrix completed much of the album's pre-production work at their
                            shared apartment.</li>
                        <li class="empty tablet_empty"></li>
                        <li class="empty phone_empty"></li>
                        <li class="image image_1 top_left_90">Chas Chandler, producer</li>
                        <li class="bottom_right_90">Are You Experienced sold more than one million copies within seven
                            months of its release.</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brett, I tried it and it worked well though I needed the second column in the big grid to be more to the right. I changed it to this: `#spring {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr auto 1.1fr;
    gap: 0.3vh;
}` Do you have any suggestions better than my solution? I mean I think it worked but it gave me another problem that I can't solve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018690/why-do-i-have-a-gap-and-how-do-i-remove-it-how-do-i-start-my-list-at-number-4