# Why do I have a gap and how do I remove it? + How do I start my list at number 4?

Tags: css

[What it´s supposed to look like at all widths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na6T4.png):

[image]

[What it looks like when the window gets smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPwWr.png)

[image]

I got this gap between the cover (green image in upper right corner) and the "track" boxes as well as between the album description and the anecdotes, when I added the grid under .anecdotes, I think. I don't get why it's there or how to get rid of it. I've tried negative margins on the image and the "track" boxes but it didn't work. The smaller the window gets, the bigger the gap is.

Edit: I realized that the gap gets smaller but doesn't go away when I remove the font-family. It doesn't matter what font I try, the gap only gets smaller when I have the default font-family.

I also wonder how to start the list in ".tracks-box-2" on number 4. I have my suspicions the problem is that the list unordered and we aren't allowed to change it so now it's an unordered list  with list-style: decimal. Tried to use the counter-reset property but can´t get it right.

Very thankful for any help

```css
/* positioning */

#spring {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr auto 1.1fr;
  gap: 0.3vh;
}

.album_data {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  margin-right: 1vh;
}


/* cover */

.cover,
.song_list {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.show_hover,
.cover:hover .show_not_hover {
  display: none;
}

.cover:hover .show_hover {
  display: initial;
}

.show_hover,
.show_not_hover {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}


/* tracks */

.song_list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1vh;
}

.tracks-box-1 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  padding: 2vh;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tracks-box-2 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 2vh;
  padding-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* this list */
}


/* anecdotes */

.anecdotes {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 0.8vh;
  margin-bottom: -1vh;
  gap: 0.7vh;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top_right_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.two_wide_bottom_left_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.brian_bell {
  background-image: url(Images/weezer-green.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 70% 50%;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5vh #003402;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bottom_right_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 5/6;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* some styling */

.h1 {
  font-family: Piximisa;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}

.h2-spring {
  font-family: Louis;
  font-size: 2.4vw;
  color: rgb(76, 148, 66);
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.musicians {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

li :not(h2>*) {
  list-style: none;
}

.tracks {
  list-style: decimal;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<article id="spring" class="best">

  <div class="album_data">
    <div>
      <h1 class="h1">SZNZ: Spring</h1>
      <h2 class="h2-spring">Released March 2022</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="musicians">
      <p>Musicians:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Rivers Cuomo, Lead vocals, backing vocals, lead guitar & writer</li>
        <li>Patrick Wilson, Drums & Writer</li>
        <li>Brian Bell, Backing vocals & lead guitar</li>
        <li>Scott Shriner, Backing vocals & bass</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="album_description">
      <p>SZNZ is a musical project by Weezer planned for release throughout 2022. The project is a collection of four short studio records to be released on the first day of each seasonal solstice, with each having its own motif, aesthetic themes, and production
        style based on the corresponding season. SZNZ: Spring is the first (of four) in the SZNZ series of EPs by Weezer.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="cover">
    <img class="show_hover" src="images/spring.jpg">
    <img class="show_not_hover" src="images/spring-2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="song_list">
    <div class="tracks-box-1">
      <h2>Tracks</h2>
      <ul class="tracks">
        <li>Opening Night</li>
        <li>Angels on Vacation</li>
        <li>A Little Bit of Love</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tracks-box-2">
      <h2></h2>
      <ul class="tracks">
        <li>The Garden of Eden</li>
        <li>The Sound of Drums</li>
        <li>All This Love</li>
        <li>Wild at heart</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="anecdotes">
    <li class="top_right_90">The album was produced by Weezer's frequent collaborators Jake Sinclair and Suzy Shinn, as well as new collaborator Ethan Gruska.</li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="two_wide_bottom_left_90">Cuomo stated that he wanted the Spring album to feature a "Happy, chill, stress-free" theme, later expressing a desire for an "acoustic, breezy" song in a similar vein to "Island in the Sun".</li>
    <li class="empty tablet_empty"></li>
    <li class="empty phone_empty"></li>
    <li class="brian_bell">Brian Bell, lead guitarist</li>
    <li class="bottom_right_90">SZNZ was officially announced via Weezer's social media pages on March 11 2022. </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: change you font-size of `trackboxes` to `rem` unit like `1rem`.people cant see the issue otherwise

Answer (score 0):

added `white-space: nowrap;` to my `li's` and changed the font-size of `.tracks-box-1` & `.tracks-box-2` to `font-size:1rem`

```css
/* positioning */

#spring {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr auto 1.1fr;
  gap: 0.3vh;
}

.album_data {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  margin-right: 1vh;
}


/* cover */

.cover,
.song_list {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.cover img {
  width: 100%;
}

.show_hover,
.cover:hover .show_not_hover {
  display: none;
}

.cover:hover .show_hover {
  display: initial;
}

.show_hover,
.show_not_hover {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}


/* tracks */

.song_list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1vh;
}

.tracks-box-1 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  padding: 2vh;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tracks-box-2 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 2vh;
  padding-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* this list */
}


/* anecdotes */

.anecdotes {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 0.8vh;
  margin-bottom: -1vh;
  gap: 0.7vh;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top_right_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.two_wide_bottom_left_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.brian_bell {
  background-image: url(Images/weezer-green.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 70% 50%;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5vh #003402;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bottom_right_90 {
  background-color: rgb(13, 88, 13);
  ;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  padding: 2vh;
  grid-column: 5/6;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* some styling */

.h1 {
  font-family: Piximisa;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}

.h2-spring {
  font-family: Louis;
  font-size: 2.4vw;
  color: rgb(76, 148, 66);
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.musicians {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

li :not(h2>*) {
  list-style: none;
}

.tracks {
  list-style: decimal;
  padding-left: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<article id="spring" class="best">

  <div class="album_data">
    <div>
      <h1 class="h1">SZNZ: Spring</h1>
      <h2 class="h2-spring">Released March 2022</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="musicians">
      <p>Musicians:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Rivers Cuomo, Lead vocals, backing vocals, lead guitar & writer</li>
        <li>Patrick Wilson, Drums & Writer</li>
        <li>Brian Bell, Backing vocals & lead guitar</li>
        <li>Scott Shriner, Backing vocals & bass</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="album_description">
      <p>SZNZ is a musical project by Weezer planned for release throughout 2022. The project is a collection of four short studio records to be released on the first day of each seasonal solstice, with each having its own motif, aesthetic themes, and production
        style based on the corresponding season. SZNZ: Spring is the first (of four) in the SZNZ series of EPs by Weezer.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="cover">
    <img class="show_hover" src="images/spring.jpg">
    <img class="show_not_hover" src="images/spring-2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="song_list">
    <div class="tracks-box-1">
      <h2>Tracks</h2>
      <ul class="tracks">
        <li>Opening Night</li>
        <li>Angels on Vacation</li>
        <li>A Little Bit of Love</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tracks-box-2">
      <h2></h2>
      <ul class="tracks">
        <li>The Garden of Eden</li>
        <li>The Sound of Drums</li>
        <li>All This Love</li>
        <li>Wild at heart</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="anecdotes">
    <li class="top_right_90">The album was produced by Weezer's frequent collaborators Jake Sinclair and Suzy Shinn, as well as new collaborator Ethan Gruska.</li>
    <li class="empty"></li>
    <li class="two_wide_bottom_left_90">Cuomo stated that he wanted the Spring album to feature a "Happy, chill, stress-free" theme, later expressing a desire for an "acoustic, breezy" song in a similar vein to "Island in the Sun".</li>
    <li class="empty tablet_empty"></li>
    <li class="empty phone_empty"></li>
    <li class="brian_bell">Brian Bell, lead guitarist</li>
    <li class="bottom_right_90">SZNZ was officially announced via Weezer's social media pages on March 11 2022. </li>
  </ul>
```